# A path towards building quantum Computing graduation project for undergraduates

Tags: programming, quantum-gate, quantum-state, ibm-q-experience, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning

I need help. I'm a computer science student with a Data science major. I have a final graduation project this year. With that, I want to create a project in the Quantum computing field. I'm already studying Quantum Computing for about two years. I have remarkably Experience in Qiskit. My question is, what exactly should I focus on in the field of Quantum to do in my graduation project? For example, should I make it with Quantum AI, or what would be good for me as a Computer Science student with a data science major? If you can suggest how I can find a good idea I can work on and develop would be great.

Thank you so much for the help